# Как взять из буфера дескриптора последние данные или очистить его?

Tags: c, unix

у меня такая ситуация, есть процесс, порожденный с помощью fork(). Он связан с родительским процессом с помощью двух pipe'ов. Он постоянно работает и пишет данные в pipe, когда основному процессу нужно, он считывает эти данные, но проблема в том, что они считываются порциями начиная с перой отправленной порции данных, что влечет за собой задержку.

Как мне считывать последние данные, или очищать буфер? Использование pipe не критично, вместо него можно использовать socketpair.

Comment: Читать много, если прочли меньше, чем запрошено, то буфер очищен, в массиве в который читали последние данные (в хвосте)

Comment: @avp, а есть способ быстрее? прочитывать весь буфер, чтоб его очистить это неочень

Comment: @avp, дочерний процесс пишет в свой поток вывода, поток вывода вроде можно очистить?

Comment: Мне неизвестно, кроме как вять ядро и подправить его под свои нужды.

Comment: Что вы называете потоком вывода?

Comment: @avp, фпйл, описываемый дескриптором с номером 1

Comment: Файл в смысле `FILE *`?

Comment: @avp, не знаю) в линксе вроде все файл)

Comment: Программа ваша? Посмотрите в код

Comment: @avp,нет, в данном случае - это вывод дочернего процесса

Comment: Я правильно понимаю, что после fork() в дочернем процессе вы соединяете pipe с дескриптором 1 и вызовом exec запускаете какую-то утилиту? И речь идет о ее stdout, на который вы хотите как-то повлиять. Если так, то imho не получится.

Comment: @avp, даже execo не вызываю ничего, просто открываю форк и с помощью pipe создаю 2 трубы, на ввод и на вывод

Comment: Тогда это должна быть *ваша программа* (ваш код). Вы пишете в pipe какой фнукцией?

Comment: posix-совместимого решения нет — только вычитывать весь буфер... но под некоторые распространённые posix-подобные системы есть способ сделать это, но т.к. на вопросе стоит метка `unix` не думаю, что будет уместно про них здесь рассказывать...